# Native binary debug with GraalVM CE

Tags: java, debugging, quarkus, graalvm

I'm using **Quarkus** with **GraalVM CE**.

For developing, it's possible to enable debug mode with maven and it works fine.
But after generation native binary (validation, production platforms), what are the best practices for debugging? Which tools could be used?

I have found this [post](https://johnaohara.github.io/2019/05/23/GraalVM-Debug-Native-Image.html) but @johnaohara uses **GraalVM EE**.
Reading [GraalVM documentation](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/tools/), I understand  that to use in production native binary with debug feature, we have to use **GraalVM EE** and pay for it?

That means in the real world **Quarkus** should build code using **GraalVM EE** and users should subscribe support to Oracle?

Please, share your experience about native binary in production and how to debug and manage it?

Thx,

Comment: Simply attache to `java.exe/|/usr/bin/java` process by the native debugger (DBG|CDB etc) you can use  C/C++ IDE for the propose (Visual Studio/Code::Blocks etc), it  will allow you to debug the native code.  2. Strongly suggesting not to use debug binaries on production.

Comment: @VictorGubinBuy default native binary doesn't contain debug symbols. Moreover, in my case, `java.exe/|/usr/bin/java` doesn't exist anymore because Graalvm converts my java program to binary.

Comment: So what the point to debug a native-image-d binary, as well as debug production servers ?  It seems like slf4j/[logback|log4j] is your only option.

Comment: no worries, this will be addressed at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that debugging native images is an EE only feature. The documentation from https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/aot-compilation/ says

> -g enables the debugging info generation. Warning: The option is available only with GraalVM Enterprise Edition.